# Does Azure Databricks charge for Terminated (Stopped) Clusters?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I was going through the [Azure Databricks pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/databricks/#pricing) and trying to find whether Databricks charge for Terminated or Stopped Cluster? Now, I understand the concept of Pay-as-you-go concept however admins in my organization instructed us to delete clusters if not used because there are some hidden charges if we create clusters. And I can't find clear document of how Databricks charge for their services.

So, stacks can anyone confirm whether this is true or not. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a charge as you can see in the linked pricing details as well:

> In addition to VM and DBU charges, you may also be charged for managed disks, public IP address, or any other resource such as Azure Storage, Azure Cosmos DB depending on your application.

It is up to you to decide whether these costs are that high that it warrants the recurring effort to delete and create clusters.

Comment: Thanks for the response Peter however I am still confused. What Azure Storage or Azure Cosmos DB has anything to do with Databricks Cluster? I mean if we are using Azure Storage then it will be billed separately anyways. How Databricks cluster on/off will make difference?

Comment: The VM uses a storage account for the disks. Turning off the cluster means turning of the VMs, but the disks of the VM are still stored on the storage account

Comment: @Shadow The cosmosdb is mentioned in the docs to clarify that if your solution uses cosmos db as a data source or sink the costs for cosmosdb is not included in the azure databrick costs so turning of the cluster doesn't mean you do not have to pay for services that are used as a data source

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to accept this as an answer.